# Need to handle the login popup in the same url (ex: IRCTC login ) via selinium using java

Tags: java, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm able to click login button in the website (IRCTC Login website) but unable to give the details to login. As the driver is still refers to the parent window.

Selenium code till clicking the login button:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util;
import java.util.Set;

import org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays.Iterator;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class JavaBasics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver.", "D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='search_btn loginText ng-star-inserted']")).click();
}
}
```

In the below snap there is a login button in the parent page. After clicking that login popup opens. Need to access and do the operations in this popup
[IRCTC login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mo8k.png)

I'm trying to switch the driver to login page.
I'm expecting to fill the details in the login page.

Comment: you haven't added the code part where you are handling the login popup